# What brand outdoor faucet is this?

Tags: plumbing

I need to know what the manufacturer is of this spigot.

[image]

Comment: ... Is that spigot being held in place by a wood screw?  That seems super-sketchy, but I guess if it works it works?

Answer (score 9):

That looks like an **OLD** version of an arrowhead 355 Series 355LF Sillcock, 3/4 in Connection, FIP x Male Hose Threaded, Solid Flange, 125 psi Pressure

https://www.supplyhog.com/c/hardware/plumbing/valves/p/arrowhead-355-series-355lf-sillcock-34-in-connection-fip-x-male-hose-threaded-solid-flange-125-psi-pressure